# How to terminate an openssl handshake from a batch file?

Tags: openssl

I have written a PHP program to execute a batch file which contains openssl commands:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect google.com:443 >test.cert
```

Taking the output of this batch file ie test.cert, I run another batch file which has these commands :

```
openssl x509 -noout -in test.cert -dates >date.txt
openssl x509 -noout -in test.cert -issuer >issuer.txt
```

But the problem is that the first batch file does not terminate because the cmd is waiting for handshake completion. So, the second batch file does not run. How do I terminate the first batch file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`openssl s_client` waits for input so you have to terminate the connection not the handshake.
the easiest way would be to change

```
 openssl s_client -showcert -connect google.com:443 > test.cert
```

to

```
 openssl s_client -showcert -connect google.com:443 < /dev/null > test.cert
```

this should close the connection right after it was established.

Answer (score 0):

```
> echo 'x' |  openssl s_client -showcert -connect google.com:443 > test.cert
```