# How to terminate OpenSSL s_client after connection

Tags: windows, batch-file, openssl

(Reviewers: I also know this is straying into SuperUser territory, but if the previous question snuck through ... :) )

This is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394378/how-to-terminate-an-openssl-handshake-from-a-batch-file), but in an Windows (7/8/Server 2008/2012) environment: I'm using the Windows port of OpenSSL.

I'm running

`openssl s_client -connect 192.168.0.1:443`

from a command prompt, in order to show certificate information. However, openssl waits for user input afterwards; I can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to "break" the output, or every just type a few characters and hit return, but I need to automate this - all I'm really interested in is the certificate information.

As per the previous question, I need some way to terminate/close the connection. However, I've tried piping in input files, `echo`ing/`type`ing input into the mix, and nothing seems to simulate a real user. Can anyone show me how to force openssl to exit after connecting?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can achieve the desired effect by using a pipe to pass in the character "Q". This makes for a great one-liner for a script:

```bash
echo "Q" | openssl s_client -connect host:port
```

If you are using a sufficiently new version of BASH, you can also use the triple less-than redirect instead of piping (some times a pipe isn't usable since it operates on stdin/stdout):

```bash
openssl s_client -connect host:port <<< "Q"
```

Comment: Instead of piping characters you can also just pipe the null device (`< NUL` on windows)

Comment: I've always done `echo | openssl s_client ...` and it never failed on me. Seems there is no need for "Q".

Comment: @MaartenBodewes The [OpenSSL v1.1.1 `s_client` documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-s_client.html) says "If end of file is reached then the connection will be closed down."

Comment: I guess the pipe will send an EOF when the end of output of `echo` is reached.

Answer (score 7):

Entering the letter 'Q' at the beginning of a blank line will end an active connection.  I've seen s_client get into states where this does not do anything, but this is the documented way to quit a session.

If you want to do this in batch mode, just create a text file with the letter 'Q' followed by a carriage return and direct it into the end of the command like so:

```
openssl s_client -connect host:port < Q.txt
```

I tried this and it works.

Comment: That looks promising, and certainly works when running OpenSSL interactively - but is there any way I can "pipe" that input to the command so I can force OpenSSL to simply connect, display the information, and exit?

Answer (score 0):

On windows I use this snippet to get the output into a variable, it writes `Q` as the first line, but it terminates:

```
$v = powershell.exe -command '&{write-host "Q" | C:\\Program` Files\\OpenSSL-Win64\\bin\\openssl.exe s_client --connect mysite:443}'
$v[0]
Q
$v[-1]   
read R BLOCK
$v.length
114
```